# Is there any way to use mssql extension with an updated version of xampp running on PHP 5.6.36?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a very old php project that is using mssql extension to communicate with sql server database. I have looked for a way to add the mssql extension to my new php version in xampp. But its not working. So is there any way to use mssql with updated version of php?

P.S. I am aware that php has stopped support for mssql from php 5.3 or higher but still if any one has some idea about how to solve the issue ,it will be really appreciated.

Comment: you should just use PDO...

Answer (score 0):

Then just use the old version of xampp (php) but keep that in mind you might face a lot is security issues I mean a lot its highly insecure so be extra careful

Comment: But can you please specify which version of xampp has a proper php version that supports mssql

Comment: You can download old XAMPP Versions in their archive at https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/

Comment: Thanks for your support